# Can't access Embedded Web Server on HP Officejet Pro 8630: "System Error"

Tags: printer, network-printer, hp-officejet

My HP Officejet Pro 8630 has started giving me this error when I try to access the Embedded Web Server (EWS) by entering the printer's IP address in a Web browser:

[image: EWS system error on HP Officejet Pro 8630]

> #### System Error
>
> An error has occurred.

Neither a network reset nor a [firmware update](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-officejet-pro-8630-e-all-in-one-printer-series/5367618/swItemId/cp-175219-2) addressed the issue. Furthermore, the printer hung while I ran a factory reset from the Settings menu, forcing me to manually power it off. I could not find any relevant diagnostic information in the printer software.

How do I fix this?

(This question should apply to the entire Officejet Pro 8600 family, including the 8610, 8620, and 8630, and variants thereof.)

Comment: Have you already reached out to HP for support on this issue? I'd be curious what the vendor that actually developed the product states about the issue. I'm not sure what web browser you're using but if IE you may try the **Compatibility Mode**. I also see others have this issue reported that refreshing the web browser multiple times lets them in at times. I also read about going to the IP in a web browser from HTTP rather than HTTPS & so forth may be a workaround too. Seems like a web interface bug that HP may need to troubleshoot their source code to resolve & post a new firmware update.

Comment: two questions: does it also have https:// page? and can you see any more details in the web page source (navigate there and press F12)?

Comment: @Nalaurien: Yes, it's HTTPS. It's configured to use always HTTPS so using HTTP will cause it to redirect to HTTPS. No, the source code of the page doesn't provide any information on the cause of the problem.

Comment: Is the network setup of the printer configured manually? IP/subnet/gateway/DNS set correctly?

Comment: Seems to be a firmware bug that may need vendor support for a 100% solution if a workaround is not acceptable. The detail of the question provided is rather vague too... Are you accessing the printer web app via IE, Chrome, some other browser from Linux, or what? Is the printer accessed via it's IP going across any routers, proxies, filters, etc.? If you're looking for a good answer, I would think you either need to disclose more detail of your setup and environment or answer back via comments I suppose on question. Perhaps you already have another answer you will add or something and waiting?

Comment: You say **"The ideal answer includes an explanation of this problem and a permanent solution to this problem"**, but you don't provide much for anyone to go off of unless they've run into this problem already or they are a lucky guesser I suppose. I never heard back from my commented questions so you are not even answering back clarification in comments for others to read to get more detail on your setup and such. I will guess this is a firmware bug that the vendor (HP) will need to address unless you have the source code, hack it, and push the firmware update yourself... that's my "guess".

Comment: @McDonald's: I've given it some thought. It looks like it's an intermittent issue as it now seems to work once again. I'm not sure what's going on here. I guess I'll have to contact HP.

Comment: I look forward to hearing what HP said the issue may be with this or if you come up with any other long-term / permanent solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed the problem myself, but I'm posting this for the benefit of future readers who run into this problem. I found the answer here: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1155387-how-to-factory-reset-hp-officejet-8610-printer-not-thru-panel

Tap the Back button four times to open the Support Menu, and under **Resets Menu**, select **Semi-full reset**. The printer will shut down automatically, and you'll go through the first-time setup when you turn it back on again.

Contrary to what the name of the command suggests, this is a factory reset; most settings will be lost. However, at least you do not need a new set of SETUP cartridges as the printhead is not new, and a few settings, such as functions administratively disabled through the EWS, are retained. The printer's page count is also retained.

---

<s>Sadly, the problem has recurred only a few days after the factory reset. I am not able to determine why. I'll have to wait for an answer from someone else...</s>

...and it looks like the issue is gone. Might be some weird bug in the EWS, who knows? I'd have to contact HP to sort this out.